# How to disable PHP Error reporting in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've read the official [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html) and all they say is that I should have a **error_reporting() function located at the top of your main index.php file.** But I don't have `index.php` file in my project. My base controller is called `core` so to get to main index I go to `www.mysite.dom/core/`. So I guess this error reporting function should be inside this controller? Then what I would like to know is where should I put it in the controller and what to put inside of it to disable the reporting. Thank you all for help, guess I am missing something :/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here is the typical structure of new Codeigniter project:

```
- application/
- system/
- user_guide/
- index.php <- this is the file you need to change
```

I usually use this code in my CI index.php. Just change local_server_name to the name of your local webserver.

With this code you can deploy your site to your production server without changing index.php each time.

```
// Domain-based environment
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'local_server_name') {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;
        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);  
            break;
        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are adding this `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to the `index.php` ? I'm little confused, because you say *With this code you can deploy your site to server without changing index.php*, but it appears as you are changing exactly the `index.php` am I wrong?

Comment: I'm changing it only once, and it display errors on my dev machine, and doesn't display on a production server.

Comment: @user1227065 if you want to have several different environments, you'd need to change it anyway. BTW, those first lines have been already changed to `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');` in the source code (no `if` is necessary later).

Answer (score 7):

Change CI index.php file to:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'local_server_name') {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')){
    switch (ENVIRONMENT){
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

IF PHP errors are off, but any MySQL errors are still going to show, turn these off in the /config/database.php file. Set the db_debug option to false:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Also, you can use **active_group** as ***development*** and ***production*** to match the environment https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

```
$active_group = 'development';


$db['development']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['development']['username'] = '---';
$db['development']['password'] = '---';
$db['development']['database'] = '---';
$db['development']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['development']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['development']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['development']['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$db['development']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['development']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['development']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['development']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['development']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['development']['stricton'] = FALSE;



$db['production']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['production']['username'] = '---';
$db['production']['password'] = '---';
$db['production']['database'] = '---';
$db['production']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['production']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['production']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['production']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['production']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['production']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['production']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['production']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['production']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['production']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['production']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to type a long query to disable error reporting in codeigniter. Use         `error_reporting(0);` in the page to disable displaying errors in that page.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i know i am very late but you can just do this : Find below code in index.php file

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

and replace **development** with **production**