# How to prevent CodeIgniters from printing PHP errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, heroku

I have a CodeIgniter PHP app running on a Heroku Cedar instance.

We are running a PHP app and we need to log errors, but NOT print them to the screen. No matter what I do, the errors are printing to the screen, which is not safe for production.

Here is the PHP code which works on my local environment and everywhere else (besides Heroku):

`error_reporting(E_ALL); #we care about all errors
ini_set('display_errors',0); #but DONT print to screen`

I have seen [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging) which suggested I try adding a custom CodeIgniter logging class, which did not work.

I also added a `phpinfo()` to the app to check if somehow my settings were being overridden downstream, but it shows that `display_errors` is set to "Off".

**So why am I STILL seeing errors printed on the screen?**

Comment: Have you tried to include these error rules in your `index.php` on the 'production' environment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773786/how-to-disable-php-error-reporting-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that CodeIgniter 2.x has some completely asinine error handling in which they use a custom error handler to ignore the developers configurations. Apparently this is fixed in [v3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/94e36fd06f5ade974cf16a7eedbf960bc3ad27ba).

I was able to fix it by just commenting out the custom error handling, which for me was located in in CodeIgniter.php, line 72...

`//set_error_handler('_exception_handler');`

Or the best solution of all: don't use CodeIgniter in the first place.

Comment: Finding the errors is the first step to fixing them. Or perhaps CodeIgniter 2.x is a framework intended only for those whose code NEVER has bugs...

Comment: Well, you can not not appreciate CI forcing you to fix all errors/warnings/notices by always printing them :). BTW, I also use CI 2.x, and din't run into this problem, did you set the `ENVIRONMENT ` variable properly?