# PHP showing errors, although display_errors is set to 0

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting, ini-set, error-suppression

I'm struggling for an hour, trying to figure out why is PHP showing errors although I suppressed them at the very begginging of my code like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

I want to log all PHP errors but I don't want to show any of them to the user as this is code for the production.

At the end of the PHP file I check if the ini is set correctly with `ini_get('display_errors')` and it returns `0` as expected. 
I also check my whole project and there is no other ini_set() function called, which could override this setting.

**Why am I still getting Undefined variable shown to the user?**

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: fb_admin</p>
<p>Filename: fb_app/header.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 173</p>

</div>
```

This is getting frustrating so thanks for any help :)

**Edit:** Of course I'm aware that I should fix this error, but that's not the point. The point is how to correctly handle other similar, unpredictable errors. **I want to log them but not to show them.**

Comment: instead of hiding the errors , you should fix the errors, it is clearing saying you , that fb_admin variable is undefined , you should use fb_admin = null; as default value and change the value when needed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a native php error, might be some library that you're using which prints those errors.

Comment: why you are using error_reporting set to `E_ALL`? it will show all errors.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim because he wants to log all errors, but not display them.

Comment: It appears you have a custom error handler defined somewhere using `set_error_handler`. Please show us that code.

Comment: Looks like CodeIgniter's default error handler to me.  Are you using CI?

Comment: Yup, I'm using Codeigniter. Of course I will fix this error and define the variable - but that's not the point :) I want to have control of other unpredicted errors that may occur and have them logged, but not shown to the user. Why is my code not doing that? :(

Comment: I've never used CodeIgniter, but I'd imagine it has it's own display / log errors flag set somewhere. Perhaps this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773786/how-to-disable-php-error-reporting-in-codeigniter